# How to fix backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync() does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, winforms

I have followed a tutorial step-by-step to ping multiple IP addresses and display either a red box or a green box respectively to the ping results (Red - Failed, Green - Success)

I am now stuck at this point where it says `backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync() does not exist in current context.`

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DataTable pingTable = new DataTable();
    List<string> ipAddress = new List<string>();
    List<PictureBox> pictureboxList = new List<PictureBox>();
    private System.Timers.Timer timer;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        timer.Interval = 5000;
        timer.Enabled = true;
        timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
    }

    private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void FillPingTable()
    {
        pingTable.Columns.Add("ip", typeof(string));
        pingTable.Columns.Add("picturebox", typeof(string));

        pingTable.Rows.Add();
        for(int i = 0; i< ipAddress.Count; i++)
        {
            pingTable.Rows.Add(ipAddress[i], pictureboxList[i]);
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Admin\Network\ipAddress.csv"))
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine();
                var values = line.Split('\n');
                ipAddress.Add(values[0]);
            }

            for(int i = 1; i<= 57; i++)
            {
                pictureboxList.Add((PictureBox)Controls.Find("pictureBox" + i, true)[0]);
            }

            FillPingTable();

            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        Parallel.For(0, ipAddress.Count(), (i, loopSate) =>
        {
            Ping ping = new Ping();
            PingReply pingReply = ping.Send(ipAddress[i].ToString());
            this.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate ()
            {
                pictureboxList[i].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
                pictureboxList[i].BackColor = (pingReply.Status == IPStatus.Success) ? Color.Green : Color.Red;
            });
        });
    }
```

I have double checked the steps and can't find what I am doing wrong here?

I am using the latest version of Visual Studio.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have your backgroundWorker1 created in the designer? Maybe you renamed it in the designer, but the code still has old field name? Obviously, you could instantiate it as a field in this file by simply adding "private BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker1 = new BackgroundWorker();" where other fields of the class are defined.

Comment: A HA!  I knew I missed something,  Had a bit of a Typo Issue :-(  Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: The only problem I have now is that it is not pinging the IP's in the csv file?

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint inside backgroundWorker1_DoWork? In case this breakpoint is not hit, you're probably missing an initial setup for your BackgroundWorker (like subscribing to its DoWork event like this backgroundWorker1.DoWork += backgroundWorker1_DoWork;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are missing *backgroundWorker1* instance. This depends on a tutorial you are following, of course.

You might have needed to create a *BackgroundWorker* component in the designer and maybe missed that step. Also, you might have renamed the component, but it wasn't renamed in your code-behind file.

Or, you needed to create the instance as a field yourself, then you could simply add the following line to the beginning of your *Form1* class:

```
private System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker1 = new BackgroundWorker();
```